# How to provide a query point as input to a PostGIS query?

Tags: postgis

Let's say I want to write a query, which returns all the coffee shops within 100 meters of a (lat, lon) pair, provided by the user.

Right now I take the lat and lon from the user and then create a point using the following functions:

`ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText('POINT (-74.1 40.2 )', 4326),900913))`

But I am not sure if this is the appropriate way to go if I later want to use `ST_DWithin(input_point, coffee.geom, 100))` to retrieve the data of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bunch of options:

*Provide a WKT string, as you're doing now:*

`ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText('POINT (-74.1 40.2 )', 4326), 900913))`

*Provide an EWKT string, including the srid:*

`ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT (-74.1 40.2 )', 900913)`

*Provide lat/lon values directly:*

`ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-74.1, 40.2), 4326), 900913)`

and many more.  Check out the [geometry constructors](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors) section of the PostGIS docs for more specialized options.